# WAMP Server VirtualHost

Tags: php, mysql, virtualhost, wampserver

I have WAMP set up, with all services running. I am able to connect to an existing database, “mysql”, both from Visual Studio Code editor and from CakePHP environment on localhost.

When adding databases, both through MySQL Console as through MyPHPAdmin, I get the following error..

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'testmysqlniels' in C:\wamp64\www\wamp_projects\WAMP Test\db_connection.php

When adding a new user and granting this user all privileges, I get the following error message. I am sure this user has all privileges so definitely also reading rights.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'niels'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\wamp_projects\WAMP Test\db_connection.php

Seems like the system in MyPHPAdmin, which I am also connected to through MySQL Console, is not the same as the one I am calling in my sketch and through CakePHP. I think the error is in the setup of my Virtualhost for my projects folder.

My sketch is on localhost, under YOURVIRTUALHOST ‘wampprojects’.
C:\wamp64\www\wamp_projects\WAMP Test (path)

Code works for existing tables, not for new ones..

My code:

```
<?php

    $dbServerName = "wampprojects";
    $dbUserName = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "testmysqlniels";

    // need to use mysqli_connect, is improved version (Improved)
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbName);


    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM help_category";
    $search_query_cost = "SELECT * FROM tables_priv";
    $search_sports = "SELECT * FROM sports_tabel";

    $result = $conn->query($search_query);
    $result_priv = $conn->query($search_sports);

    print_r($result_priv);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["name"]. " - Name <br>";
        }

    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

My DB schema shows the presence of database and tables..

So summarising, I can call all automatically included DB/ tables, nothing else added. Seems there is something wrong with my reference system..

I have read a few articles on setting up "httpd-vhosts.conf file", but nothing conclusive..

This is the current configuration of my file:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wampprojects
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/wamp_projects"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/wamp_projects/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Something else I just read is that there could be a copy of Apache already running on my PC that's confusing the routing mechanism..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On unrelated note: learn PDO instead of mysqli. mysqli is more difficult to use and has less options.

Comment: i'm not too sure you need the localhost one. What happens if you remove that and restart? Since I don't think you can have a virtualhost inside a virtualhost (assuming ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ is the same as c:/wamp64/www)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a look at PDO. I took out the localhost option in the "httpd-vhosts"  file. Same result, but removed the risk of vhost in vhost, so thanks!

Comment: Seems like when I remove the localhost part, I lose access to WAMP server start page. So I would prefer not to do so. Will try to move to another folder..

Comment: 1. Spaces in folder names are never a good idea. 2. $dbServerName = "localhost";

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eventually I found the problem. There must have been a copy of Apache Server already running on my computer. This caused me to query the wrong database copy from my code. This explains why I could access all original MySQL databases and tables, not the new ones.

What I did was quite drastic, don't know if I could have solved it otherwise. I deleted all my runtime environments using Apache, Android Studio, Java & Node.js. Also deleted Visual Studio Code. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled WAMP, then reinstalled VSC.

Hope this helps someone out!

Comment: I uninstalled series of programs, ran uninstall for WAMP an reinstalled it. So no, I don't know. How could I have checked this? Which tool?